# Image Blending Help in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

I'm somewhat new to Photoshop and Illustrator and am trying to figure out how to blend two images together. Here's the picture:[image]

It's basically a splash going into a soda background (I couldn't find a full picture that I liked). This picture works into the rest of the scene but I just need to focus on this part right now. I've tried color replacement but it doesn't match the colors correctly.

I was looking into blending techniques but I can't find one that works for what I'm trying to do. I'm basically trying to get the whole thing to blend as seamlessly as possible with each other. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: You've really not described what you want to blend. There are hard seams int eh dark area.. then the obvious edges on the right and left side. Are you trying to blend all of that or just he outer edges or just the inner seams?

Comment: Basically where the splash meets the middle (darker) drink section. I'm not worried about the inner seams right now. I was trying just to make the colors of the splash and the inner drink section blend together so it basically looks like the water splashing out from the sides. They are obviously images from two different pictures...does that make more sense at all? I may be using confusing terms...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to "sell" this, you do need to get rid of the very obvious repetitions of your "ice cubes in Coke" image *and* the splash image. In the meantime, however...

- Put all of your "drink" on one layer and take a snapshot (the camera icon at the bottom of the History panel).
- Erase enough at each end so that you have some space between the drink and the splashes.
- Set your History Brush to work from the snapshot (click in the blank square to the left of the snapshot in the History Panel.
- Set your History Brush to something fairly small (about 1/4 to 1/2 of the height of the "drink"), set its opacity to 30% and make sure it's hardness is 0%.
- Gradually paint the image back in from the history state, following the lines of the splashes. If you overdo it, use Undo or just erase what doesn't look right. The 30% opacity will let you build it up gradually.

To get the splashes to the right color, use the Clone Stamp with its blend mode set to Hue or Color (experiment to see which will work best). Clone from the drink to the splash.

Answer (score 0):

Well to start change the color using various settings such as hue/saturation so that the darknesses match

Then there's all sorts of different methods to take but an easy way is to use an oversized soft eraser - don't even touch the image just move along the outer area of the top one so you very very softly erase the edges. You should be doing this on the top image. Then its just matter of tweaking, adjusting, and tweaking some more to get it just right. Duplicating the bottom to top and doing touch up erasing work.

There are lots of other methods for 'blending' which is a fairly vague question, I'd be interested to hear other people's techniques.